# Plugins, Modules, or Component for any PHP websites (framework independent)

Tags: php, frameworks

Is there any modules/plugins/components that can be used regardless of whatever drupal, joomla, wordpress or zend framework etc or even some native php websites that are not built on any framework?

For example like chatting modules/page that can be easily integrated into your website, or blogging system or maybe login system.

Is it even possible to create such thing?

Comment: I do not know if there are any on PHP, but the concept exists, it is called a portlet:http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portlet

Answer (score 0):

There is a [Dynamic Article plug-in](http://www.tinybutstrong.com/plugins.php) which is edited for several CMS (Joomla, SPIP, PmWiki, and Drupal in beta).

This plug-in enables you to embed your web application (or you CMS component) inside an article of the CMS. The application should be developed with the [TinyButStrong](http://www.tinybutstrong.com/) template engine since the plug-in is based on it.

With such a solution, your web application can be released for several CMS with the same code.

More generally, if you don't want to embed your solution inside a CMS, TinyButStrong is a PHP template engine simple and independent that can be used as a brick in any framework or software architecture based on PHP.